# could not remove xml declaration

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, declaration, esb

I write a proxy in wso2 esb. In the proxy I change an xml file with xslt. My problem is that I want to remove   in the first line but I can not. I used omit-xml-declaration="yes" but it did not work. even I wrote seperate xslt for that but again I see it. what should I do?
this is my proxy code:

```
<sequence>

              <xslt key="gov:/first.xsl"/>
              <xslt key="gov:/RemoveXMLdeclaration.xsl"/>
              <send>
                 <endpoint>
                    <address uri="myendpoint"/>
                 </endpoint>
              </send>
              <log level="full"/>
</sequence>
```

and this is first.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0"
xmlns:gues="http://soa.ut.ac.ir/GuestIdentityService">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="gues:{local-name()}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is RemoveXMLdeclaration.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This seems to be a quirk of your XSLT engine. Apparently they have their own master stylesheet, and they only import/include yours.

Comment: any other idea?

Comment: I am not familiar with WSO2. There may be a way to configure it - refer to the documentation, or ask a question specific to that. Alternatively, apply the transformation in another application. -- BTW, the declaration should not  cause any difficulties to a well-behaved target application - perhaps it would be better to solve the *real* problem here.

Comment: when sending to an endpoint it cause problem. this a real problem.

Comment: You might want to add a tag for your environment "wso2 esb" as I don't think this is XSLT related only, if the XSLT processor serializes the result then I am sure `<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />` does work as intended but perhaps in your context the serialization is not done by XSLT. Hopefully you can find expertise if you add a tag related to that environment.